# How to tell if 2 PDFs are the same given their paths in Python?

Tags: python, pdf, compare

I have two PDFs that I would like to determine if they're equal. I don't care about the byte level but more so on appearance of the PDF. It seems that the Python package `filecmp` doesn't do the comparison justice; I get `False` when I run

```
filecamp.cmp(Path1, Path2)
```

when I know the PDFs are the same. Does anyone have any solutions to this?

Comment: `filecmp` checks if they are exactly the same, byte for byte, it's obviously not going to "look" at the PDF and make a judgement if they are visually similar. You'd need a much more complex setup for that.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on what kind of complex setups I may use for this?

Comment: You could for example export the PDFs to images and then compare the similarity of the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're certain packages to implement this. One that I used for my needs is [diff-pdf-visually](https://pypi.org/project/diff-pdf-visually/). I had to do some additional installations but otherwise works quite well.

Comment: Excited that my package is getting some use! 

Comment: Major use, still using it to this day. Really easy to use package. Thanks Brian!